# Access VBA to repeat a specific line of code

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have tried searching for this, but cannot find anything quite like what I want to do... Funny, because I would think it would be pretty simple.

I have the following code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String

strSQL1 = [Reports]![SMT_PULL_SHEET]![Text59].Value

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblJobRecordID (Job, JobRev, JobDate, JobTime) VALUES ('" & strSQL1 & "', '" & Me!Text63.Value & "', '" & Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY") & "', '" & Format(Now(), "h:mm AMPM") & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
```

This logs information for manufacturing products.  The table `tblJobRecordID` creates a unique identifier by means of an autonumber field that acts as a way to serialize each product.

I want to run `DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)` a certain number of times based on a text box populated on a report.

The intention is to insert the same record into the table a certain number of times and give each record a unique identifier in the autonumber field.

I am familiar with loops and do not want to use this method if I can help it.  Is there a simple command that tells Access to run a line of code a specific number of times?

Any help is very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Not without a loop; or some level of recursion.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid loops? What you want is to repeat a task a number of times... and that's a loop!

Comment: @Barranka, I get it.  But it seems there should be a more expedient or direct way to achieve this.  Some kind of command that says, "do this 10 times."

Comment: and that is a loop! specifically, a `for` loop!

Comment: alright alright, I'll give it a go and post when I create the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String

strSQL1 = [Reports]![SMT_PULL_SHEET]![Text59].Value

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblJobRecordID (Job, JobRev, JobDate, PrintTime, LotQty) VALUES ('" & strSQL1 & "', '" & Me!Text63.Value & "', '" & Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY") & "', '" & Format(Now(), "h:mm AMPM") & "', '" & Me!Text67.Value & "');"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False


For intCounter = 1 To [Reports]![SMT_PULL_SHEET]![Text67].Value
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
Next

DoCmd.SetWarnings True`
```

Easier than I thought to prove out the loop for this.  Thanks gentleman!